# continuous function on topology

Tags: general-topology

$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, $f(x)=2$, if $x\ge1$ and $f(x)=-2$ if $x<1$

usual topology - half open interval topology  is not continuous

half open interval topology -usual topology is continuous

and,

$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, $f(x)=2$ if $x\gt1$ and $f(x)=-2$ if $x\le1$

usual topology - half open interval topology  is not continuous

half open interval topology -usual topology is not continuous

could you please help me how can I know if it is continuous or not , I am so confuse on that my book does not explain anything about it and I did search on internet but I did not find anything please please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked everything, but I'm guessing you need to adhere to the metric-free definition of continuous namely, $f: (X,\tau) \to (Y, \tau')$ continuous $\iff f^{-1}(U) \in \tau$, for all $U \in \tau'$. I'll start you off with the second case. In this case you have $f(x) = 2$ for $[1, \infty)$ and $f(x) = -2$ for $(- \infty, 1)$. Here we have that,

$$f:(\mathbb{R}, \textbf{half-open} = \tau) \to (\mathbb{R},\textbf{usual} = \tau')$$

Let $U = (a,b)$ which is an open set in the usual topology. If $V=U \cap \{2,-2\} = \emptyset$ then $f^{-1}(V) = \emptyset$ which is in $\tau$ since $\tau$ is a topology. On the other hand, if non-empty and $(-\epsilon,\epsilon) \in V$ where $\epsilon >2$ then we see that $V = \{2,-2\}$. But then $f^{-1}(V) = [1, \infty) \cup (-\infty,1)$. Recalling that the half-open topology is generated by sets of the form $[a,b)$ and so you ask yourself, is $f^{-1}(V) \in \tau'$?

Comment: You will definitely need a metric-free def'n of continuity because the half-open topology (a.k.a. the lower-limit topology ,a.k.a. the Sorgenfrey line) is not metrizable.

Answer (score 0):

Def'n: A function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff the set $f^{-1}S=\{x\in X:f(x)\in S\}$ is an open subset of $X$ whenever $S$ is an open subset of $Y$.

The set $S=(-3,0)$ is open in both topologies on $\mathbb R$...(For the half-open topology, $S=\cup_{x\in S}[x,0)$....).

But $f^{-1}S=(-\infty,1]$ is not open in either topology, because if $1\in U$ and $U$ is open in either topology then $U\supset [1,1+r)$ for some $r>0$.